# Integrate TortoiseSVN with Redmine

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, trac, redmine, issue-tracking

I'm trying to integrate Redmine with TortoiseSVN, but I was not able to do that because TSVN always gives me this error:

> "There are no issue-tracker providers available."

I followed these steps:

- In my project folder properties, I added 'bugtraq:url -> `http://myweb/../issues/show/%BUGID%`'
- In Redmine settings, I added SVN in the repository tab, and Redmine showed my repository without any problems.

I'm not sure if there are any missing steps or what I have to do to make the integration.

Or should I look at trac, because it seems more stable and has better support?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Slightly more detail on Stefan's post:

With what you're trying to do, setting the bugtraq:url alone isn't enough. You need to either set the 'bugtraq:message' property or the 'bugtraq:logregex' property as well.
As an example, on our redmine setup we allow the following items in the commit message:

- **References**: refs,references,IssueID
- **Fixes**: fixes,closes,Fixes Bug

So we use a bugtraq:logregex for maximum flexibility of:

```
([Cc]loses|[Ii]ssue[Ii][Dd]|[Rr]eferences|[Rr]efs|[Ff]ixes(\s[Bb]ug)?)\s?#(\d+)
\d+
```

Which covers all our options.

By doing this, tortoise highlights the part of the commit comment which links into redmine and turns the number into a link which you can click on to go to the actual redmine issue.

The more advanced option is to allow you to choose an open bug directly from redmine. It's this feature that needs a specific plugin installed on your machine, but as far as I can tell, such a plugin for redmine doesn't exist, so we're kind of stuck with the basic option at the moment. When someone writes such a plug-in, and you install it, you'll then be able to go into "Issue tracker Integration" as you're currently trying to and things will work fine.

Comment: Jim, thanks great info, I want to ask if I could closes an issue in redmine when I commit with TSVN, is that possible?

Comment: Yes certainly, but only if you use the bugtraq:logregex method.
If you go to Administration->Settings->Repositories you'll find two config options: Referencing keywords and Fixing keywords. Use on of the fixing keywords in your commit log to close your issue, 
ie: fixes #55

Comment: Thanks Jim, You put me in the right direction, everything is working fine now :)

Comment: TurtleMine works well. https://github.com/jlestein/turtlemine

Answer (score 7):

Please read the [docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html).

The error "There are no issue-tracker providers available" means that you have not installed an issue tracker [plugin](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html#tsvn-dug-bugtracker-ref) for TSVN.

The bugtraq: properties don't require a plugin. You can use those without a plugin (but you won't be able to fetch a list of open issues in the commit dialog).

Comment: I have already read all these links, but I think the missing part is the COM plug-ins by redmine, right?

Comment: Yes, if they don't provide a COM plugin, you have to write your own :)

Comment: Stefan, Can I close an issues from TSvn directly when I made a commit?, also where Can I find a resource to write COM plug-ins for TSVN?

Comment: Closing issues directly from TSVN will be possible in the next version (and of course if the plugin supports it).
You can find docs on how to implement such a COM plugin here:
http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/svn/tortoisesvn/trunk/contrib/issue-tracker-plugins (username: 'guest', leave password empty)

Comment: Thanks Stefan, you have made a great work for all the developers with TSVN :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is an existing [Tortoise plugin for Redmine](http://code.google.com/p/turtlemine/) that you can try.